# Insert into a PostgreSql table from a custom-declared-type array

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I create a custom type like so:

```
CREATE TYPE employee AS (employee_id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(200), age INTEGER);
```

I then make a function which receives an array of this type as a parameter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_office(v_office_id INTEGER, v_office_name VARCHAR(400), v_employees employee[])
RETURNS void
AS $BODY$

INSERT INTO office (office_id, office_name)
VALUES(v_office_id, v_office_name)

--here I need to insert the array of employees (v_employees) into the employees table

$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Given that the employees table is set up to match the properties of the employee type:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (employee_id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(200), age INTEGER)
```

How can I simply transfer this array of type employee to the employee table? Despite several attempts, I can't get the syntax right. (PostgreSql 9.6)

Comment: Unrelated but: storing the `age` of a person is really bad design. You should store the date of birth - the age can easily be calculated from that.

Comment: Also: if you create a table `employee` you **automatically** have a type with the same name. There is no need to create a separate type. You can use a table's type as a parameter type in Postgres

Comment: Oh really so I could just delete the type (which has the same name as the table) and all should work? I'll try that - thanks.

Comment: Correct. You don't need a type that is identical to your table definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest the elements of the array:

```
insert into employees (employee_id, name, age)
select employee_id, name, age
from unnest(v_employees);
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way I can access type properties (or columns) once unnested? (for example I may need to check conflicts on employee.employee_id, and then update certain fields, i.e. employee.name)

Comment: @FBryant87: the unnested array will automatically give you access to the columns. See my edit